# What's the fastest way to get the record of a row of data?

Tags: php, mysql

So I was having a test around with a large database table of users that has just over 1 million rows of data, attempting to come up with some kind of "user rank" but it seems very slow in comparison to any other way I use this data so I was wondering if I was going about it the wrong way or not.
I'm pulling every row of data with the two columns `id` and `points`, grouping by points so people with the same points will be the same rank and then ordering in descending order.

Here's a quick throw together I did to test it out:

```
<?php
session_start();
$rank = 0;
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, points FROM users GROUP BY points ORDER BY points DESC");
$query->execute();
foreach($query as $result){
    $rank += 1;
    if($result['id'] == $_SESSION['myid']){
        echo '' . $_SESSION['myuser'] . ' is rank ' . number_format($rank) . ' globally.';
    }
}
```

`points` and `id` are indexed

This seemed to load quite slowly, not 'really' slow but slower than I'd like so I decided to do some testing with it and check how long the script was taking to execute using the following method:

```
<?php
$starttime = microtime(true);
session_start();
$rank = 0;
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, points FROM users GROUP BY points ORDER BY points DESC");
$query->execute();
foreach($query as $result){
    $rank += 1;
    if($result['id'] == $_SESSION['myid']){
        echo '' . $_SESSION['myuser'] . ' is rank ' . number_format($rank) . ' globally.';
    }
}
$endtime = microtime(true);
$duration = $endtime - $starttime;
echo '<br /><br />This page took ' . $duration . ' seconds to load.';
```

This averaged at 1.9468239237 seconds to load based on 1000 loads.

I then added a `break;` in the loop when it finds your rank thinking maybe it would shorten the processing time but to no avail.

So my question is, is there a better way you calculate something like this?

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN on your query to see if the index is actually being used?

Comment: you shouldn't do `GROUP BY points` if you want to get all `id` to compare later on `if($result['id'] == $_SESSION['myid']){`  your query returns random `id` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56bc9d/1

Comment: @chris85 But that would only get one row... It needs to calculate your number based on EVERYONE's points otherwise it would always return that you're ranked #1.

Comment: @MarkBaker I have indeed. The index is in use.

Comment: @Alex You're absolutely correct, bad overlook on my part. Thank you. Still slower than a leaf falling though.

Comment: Can you run this query on a MySQL CLI and let us know how much time is MySQL and how much time is PHP? You may need to compensate for the slowness of the writing of stuff in a console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05189/3

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, points, IF(@rank IS NULL,@rank:=1,@rank:=@rank+1) rank
  FROM users 
  ORDER BY points DESC) t
ON u.id = t.id
WHERE u.id = 3; # <- 3 is id you are looking for
```

Comment: This returns as always rank 1 no matter what the `id` is.

Comment: what? did you check my fiddle?

Comment: This doesn't appear to group users.

Comment: I did, yes. My bad, I messed up on it in testing. There's nothing wrong with this and it's took the query down to 0.3 second average. Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel as I mentioned in comment to OP, it seems he does not need any `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Alex you're correct that using `GROUP BY` in that way would cause bugs. However, I don't think he said that he didn't want the `GROUP BY` at all. The way you have it, people with the same number of points will get arbitrarily different ranks.

Comment: Well the way I'm displaying the rank using a comparison to the session `myid`. Would this not return null after grouping if a user has the same points as another?

Comment: no WilliamKunkel means that my query returns different rank for users with same point. As you can see in my fiddle users 1,2,3 have all same 1 point got ranks: 2,3,4  So @Equinox04 you should comment how you want to proceed? do you want all of them to get same rank? so you can have even 100 users with rank=1? or you want to keep rank separately but a bit random?

Comment: @Alex I didn't want it grouped, honestly. This answer was just the thing I was looking for.

Comment: @Alex - Thanks. I was just wondering, what is it about this query that has shaved a whopping 2 seconds off my original query? This seems to be "doing" a bit more so it's quite confusing how it would be faster. Is it the `where` clause and because it's indexed?

Comment: @Equinox04 your first query was even more performant then mine here. but it takes time on php side to loop through results till the record you need. and it takes more resources just to pass bigger result set from mysql to php.

Answer (score 1):

You could try altering your query to this:

```
SELECT id, Name, 1+(SELECT count(*) from users u1 WHERE u1.Points > u1.Points) as Rank, Points
FROM users u WHERE u.id = your_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would want to try something like this

```sql
SELECT users.id, ranks.rank
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT points, ROW_NUMBER() AS rank
    FROM users
    GROUP BY points
    ORDER BY points DESC
) ranks ON users.points = ranks.points
WHERE users.id = ?
```

Where you prepare the query with your user's id.

**Edit:** It appears that MySQL does not have a ROW_NUMBER() function. This should work instead:

```sql
SELECT users.id, ranks.rank
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.points, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
        SELECT points
        FROM users
        GROUP BY points
        ORDER BY points DESC
    ) t1, (SELECT @rank := 0) t2 
) ranks ON users.points = ranks.points
WHERE users.id = ?
```